# pip installation of gmpy2

Tags: python, pip, gmpy

When I used pip to install gmpy2, I always got the version 1.16, i.e. gmpy instead of gmpy2.

```
$ pip search gmpy
gmpy                      - GMP or MPIR interface to Python 2.4+ and 3.x
  INSTALLED: 1.16 (latest)
```

Is there any way to directly install gmpy2 through pip?

Answer (score 4):

I have added gmpy2 to the [Python Package Index](http://pypi.python.org/pypi).

gmpy2 requires GMP 5.0 or later, MPFR 3.1 or later, and MPC 1.0 or later. You may need to compile your own version of those libraries if your operating system doesn't provide the latest versions. Please see [Installing GMPY2](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/wiki/InstallingGmpy2) for details.

Answer (score 1):

[gmpy2](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/) is now in beta. I think this is why it is not available in pypi.

Comment: Correct. Since gmpy2 also requires very recent versions of MPFR and MPC which frequently aren't yet available on many Linux distributions, manual intervention is frequently required anyway. I will add the next release of gmpy2 to PyPi. (I'm the maintainer of gmpy and gmpy2.)

Answer (score 0):

No. GMPY2 is not in the [Python Package Index](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=search&term=gmpy&submit=search), which `pip` uses. Only version 1.16 is. It seems like their documentation on Google Code might be wrong.