# Elementwise operations in mpmath slow compared to numpy and its solution

Tags: python, numpy, factorial, mpmath

I have some calculations that involve factorials that explode pretty fast so I resolved to use the arbitrary precision library `mpmath`.

The code I have looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import mpmath as mp
import time

a    = np.linspace( 0, 100e-2, 100 )
b    = np.linspace( 0, np.pi )
c    = np.arange( 30 )

t    = time.time()
M    = np.ones( [ len(a), len(b), len(c) ] )
A, B = np.meshgrid( a, b, indexing = 'ij' )
temp = A**2 + B
temp = np.reshape( temp, [ len(a), len(b), 1 ] )
temp = np.repeat( temp, len(c), axis = 2 )
M   *= temp
print 'part1:      ', time.time() - t
t    = time.time()

temp = np.array( [ mp.fac(x) for x in c ] )
temp = np.reshape( temp, [ 1, 1, len(c) ] )
temp = np.repeat(  temp, len(a), axis = 0 )
temp = np.repeat(  temp, len(b), axis = 1 )
print 'part2 so far:', time.time() - t
M   *= temp
print 'part2 finally', time.time() - t
t    = time.time()
```

The thing that seems to take the most time is the very last line and I suspect it is because `M` has a bunch of `float`s and `temp` has a bunch of `mp.mpf`s. I tried initializing `M` with `mp.mpf`s but then everything slowed down.

This is the output I get:

```
part1:        0.00429606437683
part2 so far: 0.00184297561646
part2 finally 1.9477159977
```

Any ideas how I can speed this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gmpy2` is significantly faster that `mpmath` for this type of calculation. The following code runs about 12x faster on my machine.

```
import numpy as np
import gmpy2 as mp
import time

a = np.linspace(0, 100e-2, 100)
b = np.linspace(0, np.pi)
c = np.arange(30)

t = time.time()
M = np.ones([len(a), len(b), len(c)])
A, B = np.meshgrid( a, b, indexing = 'ij' )
temp = A**2+B
temp = np.reshape(temp, [len(a), len(b), 1])
temp = np.repeat(temp, len(c), axis=2)
M *= temp
print 'part1:', time.time() - t
t = time.time()

temp = np.array([mp.factorial(x) for x in c])
temp = np.reshape(temp, [1, 1, len(c)])
temp = np.repeat(temp, len(a), axis=0)
temp = np.repeat(temp, len(b), axis=1)
print 'part2 so far:', time.time() - t
M *= temp
print 'part2:', time.time() - t
t = time.time()
```

`mpmath` is written in Python and normally uses Python's native integers for its computations. If `gmpy2` is available, it will use the faster integer type provided by `gmpy2`. If you just need one of the functions that is provided directly by `gmpy2`, then using `gmpy2` directly is usually faster.

**Update**

I ran a few experiments. What's actually happening may not be what you expect. When you calculate `temp`, the values can either be an integer (`math.factorial`, `gmpy.fac`, or `gmpy2.fac`) or a floating-point value (`gmpy2.factorial`, `mpmath.fac`). When `numpy` computes `M *= temp`, all the values in `temp` are converted to a 64-bit float. If the value is an integer, the conversion raises an OverflowError. If the value is a floating point number, the conversion returns infinity. You can see this by changing `c` to `np.arange(300)` and print `M` at the end. If you use `gmpy.fac` or `math.factorial`, you will get and `OverflowError`. If you use `mpmath.factorial` or `gmpy2.factorial`, you won't get an `OverflowError` but the resulting `M` will contain infinities.

If you are trying to avoid the `OverflowError`, you will need to calculate `temp` with floating point values so the conversion to a 64-bit float will result in infinity.

If you aren't encountering `OverflowError`, then `math.factorial` is the fastest option.

If you are trying to avoid both `OverflowError` and infinities, then you'll need to use either the `mpmath.mpf` or the `gmpy2.mpfr` floating point types throughout. (Don't try to use `gmpy.mpf`.)

**Update #2**

Here is an example that uses `gmpy2.mpfr` with a precision of 200 bits. With `c=np.arange(30)`, it is ~5x faster than your original example. I show it using `c = np.arange(300)` since that would either generate an `OverflowError` or infinities. The total running time for the larger range is about the same as your original code.

```
import numpy as np
import gmpy2
import time

from gmpy2 import mpfr

gmpy2.get_context().precision = 200

a = np.linspace(mpfr(0), mpfr(1), 100)
b = np.linspace(mpfr(0), gmpy2.const_pi())
c = np.arange(300)

t = time.time()
M = np.ones([len(a), len(b), len(c)], dtype=object)
A, B = np.meshgrid( a, b, indexing = 'ij' )
temp = A**2+B
temp = np.reshape(temp, [len(a), len(b), 1])
temp = np.repeat(temp, len(c), axis=2)
M *= temp
print 'part1:', time.time() - t
t = time.time()

temp = np.array([gmpy2.factorial(x) for x in c], dtype=object)
temp = np.reshape(temp, [1, 1, len(c)])
temp = np.repeat(temp, len(a), axis=0)
temp = np.repeat(temp, len(b), axis=1)
print 'part2 so far:', time.time() - t
M *= temp
print 'part2:', time.time() - t
t = time.time()
```

Disclaimer: I maintain `gmpy2`.

Comment: Wow! 12x! I ran it with gmpy (I previously had set `MPMATH_NOGMPY`)  but it only did a 40% speed up at best. Also, my `mp.libmp.BACKEND` is `gmpy` not `gmpy2` is there a difference?

Comment: Oops. I pasted in the wrong code. I was using `gmpy2` directly. I'll edit the answer in a minute. `gmpy2` provides full access to the MPFR (correctly rounded real floating point) and MPC (correctly rounded complex floating point) arbitrary precision libraries. The older `gmpy` doesn't support MPFR and MPC.

Comment: hm... I just noticed that the only change you've made is what factorial function is used. The thing that is slowing my code down is the last `M*=temp` not the `mp.fac(x)` operation. Does the backend matter in this case this much?

Comment: Please double-check the import statements... I am not using mpmath at all. It's not just changing the backend: it's using gmpy2 instead of mpmath.

Comment: I think I get it... in the sense that you're saying `gmpy2` elements will do the `M *= temp` operation much faster correct?

Comment: ok I haven't managed to install `gmpy2` but worked like a charm with `gmpy`

Comment: Please see my updated answer. And I highly recommend using `gmpy2` instead of `gmpy` for floating point arithmetic.

Comment: So the problem with that is one I tried installing gmpy2 and I think I've made a mess :( and the second even if I install it locally the admins on the shared computer where I actually run stuff won't go through anything more than a `sudo apt-get` or `pip install` etc command, reading through your update now. Thanks very much either way!!

Comment: you're a genius. I got an `OverflowError` error as you suggested. As you may expect the desired outcome is to avoid both the `OverflowError` and the infs so I assume that gmpy2 is the way to go. I think I'll post another question about "easy installation" of gmpy2

Comment: Actually I think I found the answer to my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178594/pip-installation-of-gmpy2#comment19650274_14179137 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178594/pip-installation-of-gmpy2/14180357#14180357